# how to check in array if key exists in a separate array and print respective values?

Tags: php, arrays

So, i have 2 arrays. One is with key and values, the other one is just keys. I need to check if keys in first array are matched with the keys from second array and print respective value. Goal is to make a csv.

First print keys from second array on the top and then print respective values below for each array which is obtained from some api. Right now the problem is that values are not printed respectfully with keys.

For printing values i have this function:

```
function displayArrayRecursively($arr, $vars) {
    if ($arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($key)) {
                //
                displayArrayRecursively($key, $vars);
            }
            elseif (is_array($value)) {
                //
                displayArrayRecursively($value, $vars);
            }
            else {
                //  Output
                $value = $value ? str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n", PHP_EOL), "", $value): '';
                
                foreach ($vars as $var) {
                    if ($key === $var) {
                        echo(strip_tags($value) . "~");
                    }
                }
                }
                
            }
        }
}
```

Vars are something like this:

```
$vars = array(    ...
    "email_direkt",
    "tel_zentrale",
    "ausstatt_beschr",
    "id",
    "ji_objektstatus",
    "ji_objektstatus_id",
    "bauart_id",
    "url"
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `array_intersect_key()` where one array is is your key=>value set, and the other is your keys run through `array_flip()`

Comment: @Scuzzy can you please give me example? Thanks

Comment: Consider adding representative sample data that we can play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what youre after

First we have your source of data in `$array`, and then the keys you want to pick out, if you need them sorted, you can use the `array_merge` thing below.

The `array_intersect_key` will filter out keys based on the second paramter,

```
$array = array('a'=>'AAA','b'=>'BBB','c'=>'CCC','d'=>'DDD','e'=>'EEE');

$keys = array('e','a','c');

$result = array_intersect_key( $array, array_flip( $keys ) ); // AAA/CCC/EEE

// Additional sort
$result = array_merge( array_flip( $keys ), $result ); // EEE/AAA/CCC
```